# pyspark method to get only update and new records

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark

I am using pyspark2.1 below are my dataframes

YesterdayDataDF

1,Nagraj,Keshav,2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000,2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000,20171120060038

2,Raghu,HR,2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000,2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000,20171120060038

TodayDataDF

1,Nagraj,K,2017-11-21 00:02:39.867000000,2017-11-21 00:02:39.867000000

2,Raghu,HR,2017-11-21 00:02:39.867000000,2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000

3,Ramya,Govindaraju,2017-11-21 00:02:39.867000000,2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000

My Output

1,Nagraj,K,2017-11-21 00:02:39.867000000,2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000,20171120060038

3,Ramya,Govindaraju,2017-11-21 00:02:39.867000000,2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000,20171120060038

I should not be getting the record that is present in both the dataframes since there is change in only first record in names I should get this record and record number 3 is new record.

I used below logic

```
df =today_data_df.select("id").subtract(yesterdata_data_df.select("id")).toDF('d1').join(today_data_df,col('d1')==today_data_df.id).drop('d1')
```

output is:

3,Ramya,Govindaraju,2017-11-21 00:02:39.867000000,2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000,20171120060038

But I should be getting below as given below please help

1,Nagraj,K,2017-11-21 00:02:39.867000000,2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000,20171120060038
3,Ramya,Govindaraju,2017-11-21 00:02:39.867000000,2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000,20171120060038

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that there is one name field which contains ','

```
ydata=[(1,'Nagraj,Keshav','2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000','2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000',20171120060038),(2,'Raghu,HR','2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000','2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000',20171120060038)]
yschema=['id','name','fdate','tdate','stamp']
tdata=[(1,'Nagraj,K','2017-11-21 00:02:39.867000000','2017-11-21   00:02:39.867000000',20171120060038),(2,'Raghu,HR','2017-11-21 00:02:39.867000000','2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000',20171120060038),(3,'Ramya,Govindaraju','2017-11-21 00:02:39.867000000','2017-11-20 00:02:39.867000000',20171120060038)]
ydf=spark.createDataFrame(ydata,yschema)
tdf=spark.createDataFrame(tdata,yschema)
newdf=tdf.select('id','name').subtract(ydf.select('id','name'))

newdf.join(tdf,newdf['id']==tdf['id']).drop(tdf['id']).drop(tdf['name']).show()
```

Output:

```
    | id|             name|               fdate|               tdate|           stamp|
    +---+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+
    |  1|         Nagraj,K|2017-11-21 00:02:...|2017-11-21   00:02:...|20171120060038|
    |  3|Ramya,Govindaraju|2017-11-21 00:02:...|2017-11-20 00:02:...|20171120060038|
```

Comment: Thank you Sony, for the solution. If I get new columns should I increase the columns in select statement of subtract ?

Comment: It depends on your condition for new insert and update.suppose if you have added a new column(phone_no) and you want to get all records in output whose name,phone_no got changed or got added then you should add the phone_no in select statement of subtract.